# Can't create ```TokenName``` using ```tokenName``` with error ```GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: ...```

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, smart-contract, nft, haskell

I'm not sure is relevant but the code in question is for a generic Validator (with Datums and Redeemers) used to get a forwarded minting policy

the problem should be clear from the title, I can't get to construct a `TokenName` value starting form a ``ByteString```

I assume the rror is dued to the `plutus-tx-plugin` library so all the `ghc-options` specified in the [troubleshooting section for the Plutus documentation](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/plutus/troubleshooting.html#plugin-errors) are enabled (without much success)

the error I get is the following

```
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Type constructor: GHC.Prim.Char#
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Prim.Char#
Context: Compiling data constructor type: GHC.Types.C#
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Types.Char
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Base.String
Context: Compiling expr: PlutusTx.Base.$ @ GHC.Base.String
Context: Compiling expr: PlutusTx.Base.$
                           @ GHC.Base.String @ Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName
Context: Compiling expr: PlutusTx.Base.$
                           @ GHC.Base.String
                           @ Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName
                           (PlutusTx.Base..
                              @ Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
                              @ Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName
                              @ GHC.Base.String
                              Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.tokenName
                              Data.ByteString.Char8.pack)
```

and keeps expanding for a while...

I know for sure (by commenting out) the code causing this is the following:

> ***NOTE:*** I've commented out everything related to `collectionCurrencySymbol` from the moment that is causing problems too and I'll likely change it, any idea is welcome but is not the main point of the question

```
 expectedTokenName :: Value.TokenName
 expectedTokenName =  Value.tokenName $ "My Awesome NFT collection #" <> integerToBS8 datumCounter

 -- collectionCurrencySymbol :: Value.CurrencySymbol
 -- collectionCurrencySymbol = (Value.mpsSymbol . Ledger.mintingPolicyHash . mkForwardingMintingPolicy ) (Ctx.ownHash ctx)

singleTokenMinted :: PTxP.Bool
singleTokenMinted =
  case Value.flattenValue (txInfoMint ( Ctx.scriptContextTxInfo ctx) ) of
    [( mintedCurrencySym , mintedTokenName , mintedAmount )] ->
      -- mintedCurrencySym == collectionCurrencySymbol   PTxP.&&
      mintedTokenName   == expectedTokenName          PTxP.&&
      mintedAmount      == 1
    _                                                        ->
      traceError "minting more than 1 AssetClass"
```

where `integerToBS8` is as simple as :

```
{-# INLINEABLE integerToBS8 #-}
integerToBS8 :: Integer -> BS8.ByteString
integerToBS8 int
    | int == 0 = BS8.pack "0"
    | int == 1 = BS8.pack "1"
    | int == 2 = BS8.pack "2"
    | int == 3 = BS8.pack "3"
    | int == 4 = BS8.pack "4"
    | int == 5 = BS8.pack "5"
    | int == 6 = BS8.pack "6"
    | int == 7 = BS8.pack "7"
    | int == 8 = BS8.pack "8"
    | int == 9 = BS8.pack "9"
    | otherwise = integerToBS8 ( int `div` 10 ) <> integerToBS8 ( int `mod` 10 )
```

some conventions I use

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8       as BS8
import qualified Ledger.Contexts as Ctx
import qualified Ledger.Value as Value
import qualified Ledger
import PlutusTx.Prelude as PTxP
```

It seems to me `GHC` just doesn't like raw strings (since `OverloadedStrings` is just adding silently a bunch of `pack` form the `IsString` typeclass where needed)

any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `tokenName` is not meant to be used on-chain

[see this closed issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/498)

due to the fact of `:t tokenName` being `ByteString -> TokenName` ( and not `BuiltinByteString -> TokenName`) the correct way to build dynamically a `TokenName` is by using the `TokenName` constructor itself (and NOT the helper function)